# Make a layout with one title, two contents, second content aligned to center of main div

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

So, I want to have this layout: 1 title above. 2 divs, the first one on the left side, the second one aligned below title. But with my code, the matches from the *match-display* div are aligned to the center of *match-display* div itself. How can I do to align it to the center of the main div? (aligned like *title* div). Do I have to use Grid, just flexbox, or something else.

```css
.main{
background-color:red;
text-align: center;
}

.container{
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}

.title{
display: block;
}

.league{
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}

.stadium-date{
   display:flex;
   flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.info{
flex: 1;
text-align: center;
}

.info img{
  width: 50%;
}

.match-display{
flex: 1 100%;
}

.match{
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;    
     align-items: center;
}

.match img{
width: 5%;
}

.main-match{
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to left, red 0%, red 25%, black 50%, red 75%, red 100%) 100% 0 100% 0/3px 0 3px 0 stretch;
}
```

```html
            <div class="main">
                    <span class="title">
                        NEXT MATCH
                    </span>
                    
                <div class="container">

                    <div class="info">
                        <div class="league">
                            <img src="https://image.similarpng.com/very-thumbnail/2020/12/Lorem-ipsum-logo-isolated-clipart-PNG.png">
                            <span class="text-info">League</span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="stadium-date">
                            <span class="text-info">Stadium, Location</span>
                            <span class="date-info">26.06.2022</span>
                            <img src="https://image.similarpng.com/very-thumbnail/2020/12/Lorem-ipsum-logo-isolated-clipart-PNG.png">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="match-display">
                        <div class="match">
                            <img src="https://image.similarpng.com/very-thumbnail/2020/12/Lorem-ipsum-logo-isolated-clipart-PNG.png">
                            VS.
                            <img src="https://image.similarpng.com/very-thumbnail/2020/12/Lorem-ipsum-logo-isolated-clipart-PNG.png">
                        </div>

                        <div class="match main-match">
                            <img src="https://image.similarpng.com/very-thumbnail/2020/12/Lorem-ipsum-logo-isolated-clipart-PNG.png">
                            VS.
                            <img src="https://image.similarpng.com/very-thumbnail/2020/12/Lorem-ipsum-logo-isolated-clipart-PNG.png">
                        </div>

                        <div class="match">
                            <img src="https://image.similarpng.com/very-thumbnail/2020/12/Lorem-ipsum-logo-isolated-clipart-PNG.png">
                            VS.
                            <img src="https://image.similarpng.com/very-thumbnail/2020/12/Lorem-ipsum-logo-isolated-clipart-PNG.png">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an example where I adjust the HTML and add the `title section` to the `match-display section` so you can easily align it. See https://codepen.io/nickvanloocke/pen/RwMbQKE

So in this example you have two separated blocks one left (info) and one right (match-display) and no more top block for the title. I am not sure if this is going to work for you but I can't think of any other decent option.

Except set the info div to `position: absolute;` so you can set the match-display to full width and align it to the title, but here is the downside that your info bar is absolute positioned, see https://codepen.io/nickvanloocke/pen/VwXZQyV.